# How do I install a go module?

Tags: go, go-modules

Usually, when i'm in a workspace, all I need to do is `go install` to install an executable into my `pkg` folder. However, let's say i'm creating a module outside of `$GOPATH/src`. I then have a folder called `ModuleTest` on my desktop that contains the `go.mod` file. How do I install the package I created so I can use it in other go programs.

I've tried running `go get` and `go install` while inside the `ModuleTest` folder but it doesn't install anything into `$GOPATH/pkg` or `$GOPATH/bin`.

EDIT: I guess what i'm asking is, how do I install a go module locally without first pushing it on github and then doing `go get`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `replace` keyword.

It will be something like this:

```
module github.com/a/b

replace github.com/foo/bar => /Users/YourName/Projects/bar

require (
    github.com/foo/bar v1.0.0
)
```

Answer (score -1):

For it to reflect in `$GOPATH/bin` you need to do `go get -u .......` instead of `go get .......`.

Hope it helps :)